# how can i simulate user fill forms inputs with browser's console

Tags: javascript, jquery, console

in some web forms by difference policies we can't use jquery in  browser's console to fill input form and in this case we should simulate human actions to form works well.
is there any solution to simulate human fill form (keypress function or etc)?

for an example you could test fill instagram login form.

Answer (score 1):

In forms that do not use jquery, you can do this by injecting a jquery file.

```
javascript: (function (){
    function loadScript(u, i) {
        var d = document;
        if (!d.getElementById(i)) {
            var s = d.createElement('script');
            s.src = u;
            s.id = i;
            d.body.appendChild(s);
        }
    } loadScript('https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js', 'jquery');
})();
```

Comment: thanks but it not work on instagram login form 
because it had refused load the script ...